# getting WebView history from WebBackForwardList

Tags: android, webview, browser-history

How do i get the history of a WebView using the **WebBackForwardList** class? I looked at the [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebBackForwardList.html) but i could not understand it, is **WebBackForwardList** the proper way to access the history of WebView? I intend to parse the history to a ListView, I cannot find any examples of how to access the history of WebView, What is the proper method to get the history?

Comment: What is it exactly, that you do not understand? The WebBackForwardList is a list of WebHistoryItems with a size, that is the sum of backward and forward items. If you go backwards from the current index down to 0, you can fetch the back-items. If you go up from current index to getSize-1, you can fetch the forward items (pages which where visited and then back was pressed.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your webView instance, just use copyBackForwardList(), for example

WebBackForwardList wbfl = webView.copyBackForwardList();

Then setup a for-loop to scan the list, pull entries (e.g., title, URL), and send them to your ListView (or whatever).

Comment: i am always getting empty list on calling webview.copyBackForwardList(); , what could be the reason

Answer (score 7):

Yeah,
you can use 
[WebBackForwardList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebBackForwardList.html)

Example:

```
public void getBackForwardList(){
    WebBackForwardList currentList = this.copyBackForwardList();
    int currentSize = currentList.getSize();
    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; ++i)
    {
        WebHistoryItem item = currentList.getItemAtIndex(i);
        String url = item.getUrl();
        LOG.d(TAG, "The URL at index: " + Integer.toString(i) + " is " + url );
    }
}
```