# Unable to get correct URL in Android webview

Tags: android, url, mobile, webview, android-webview

In an Android web view, I'm trying to get the URL of webpages visited by the user. I'm using:

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
```

Unfortunately, for certain cases all of the above return me the wrong URL. For example when I'm on `http://www.yahoo.com` I get the correct URL, but once I click on any news article, the URL returned to me is *still* `http://www.yahoo.com`.

Just to confirm, I opened http://www.yahoo.com on Chrome, and then tapped the same articles to check whether Chrome gets the correct URLs. It does, which means it's possible and I'm probably missing something fundamental.

How can I get that URL in my own webview? Note that I have tried the [JavaScript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993207/4936905) as well, but it's been of no use.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365668/getting-webview-history-from-webbackforwardlist

Comment: That relates to the history of a WebView using the **WebBackForwardList class**.